# NullPointerException on onFocusSearch in BrowseFragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

I'm working in an Android TV app with a `MainFragment` that extends `BrowseFragment` and sometimes it crashes in the method `onFocusSearch(View focused, int direction)` defined for `mOnFocusSearchListener` in the `BrowseFragment`:

```
private final BrowseFrameLayout.OnFocusSearchListener mOnFocusSearchListener =
        new BrowseFrameLayout.OnFocusSearchListener() {
    @Override
    public View onFocusSearch(View focused, int direction) {
        // if headers is running transition,  focus stays
        if (mCanShowHeaders && isInHeadersTransition()) {
            return focused;
        }
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "onFocusSearch focused " + focused + " + direction " + direction);

        if (getTitleView() != null && focused != getTitleView() &&
                direction == View.FOCUS_UP) {
            return getTitleView();
        }
        if (getTitleView() != null && getTitleView().hasFocus() &&
                direction == View.FOCUS_DOWN) {
            return mCanShowHeaders && mShowingHeaders ?
                    mHeadersFragment.getVerticalGridView() :
                   mMainFragment.getView();
        }

        boolean isRtl = ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(focused) == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
        int towardStart = isRtl ? View.FOCUS_RIGHT : View.FOCUS_LEFT;
        int towardEnd = isRtl ? View.FOCUS_LEFT : View.FOCUS_RIGHT;
        if (mCanShowHeaders && direction == towardStart) {
            if (isVerticalScrolling() || mShowingHeaders) {
                return focused;
            }
            return mHeadersFragment.getVerticalGridView();
        } else if (direction == towardEnd) {
            if (isVerticalScrolling()) {
                return focused;
            }
            return mMainFragment.getView(); //*****CRASH******
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
};
```

Note: The line where crash happens is marked with `//*****CRASH******`.
This crash doesn't always appears,but when it does says that `mMainFragment` is `null`...

Can't find the problem. Help!

Updating leanback library, would help?

Comment: Don't keep references to fragments, try to get them from the `FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 0):

The `onFocusSearchListener` should be set after `onStart` is called in  `BrowseFragment`. The crash is most likely because `mMainFragment` is null or the view it is returning is null since it hasn't actually been added yet. By the time `onStart` is called, the `mMainFragment` life cycle methods will have been called (including `onCreateView`).

It looks like they're setting it in `onCreate`. So what you could do is grab the `BrowseFrameLayout` that this listener is being set on, save the listener they set on it, null out the listener, and then set it back in `onStart` in your subclass of `BrowseFragment`.

In `onCreateView` of your `BrowseFragment` subclass:

```
    BrowseFrameLayout mBrowseFrame = (BrowseFrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.browse_frame);
    OnFocusSearchListener mOnFocusSearchListener = mBrowseFrame.getOnFocusSearchListener();
    mBrowseFrame.setOnFocusSearchListener(null);
```

Then in `onStart` of your `BrowseFragment` subclass:

```
   mBrowseFrame.setOnFocusSearchListener(mOnFocusSearchListener);
```

Comment: How can I access onFocusSearchListener so I can set it in `onStart` method in my subclass?

Comment: I think there are many ways to go about this to try and solve the issue. I originally assumed you were setting your own `OnFocusSearchListener`. One option is to disable focus until `onStart`. Another is to write a wrapper around `mOnFocusSearchListener` which only calls `mOnFocusSearchListener` if `mMainFragment` isn't null. But posted another solution more similar to my first suggestion above. Please feel free to try all of those options out.